# Does the boost enable_shared_from_this feature add too much size to the binary?

Tags: c++, boost

I didn't know if this question is suitable for SO, but there we go:

When enabling shared_from_this, does it adds too much size to the executable? Does it also take too much time to resolve the shared_from_this() call?

Looking around the docs, enable_shared_from_this is a helper that just adds two functions, so I think it shouldn't take too much extra size.

**EDIT** A more suitable title for this question should be, how much size does it add? instead of asking if it adds too much size.

Comment: How much is too much, why don't you try and see if it is acceptable to you.

Comment: You're right, this problem may fit a specific context. By too much, I mean more than... let's say 4 bytes for each class or instance of that class. I don't have a specific context, it's just matter of curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When enabling shared_from_this, does it adds too much size to the executable?

At *runtime*, it will add the size of a `weak_ptr` to each instantiated object, which in the current version of boost, is **the size of 2 pointers.**

As for the *executable binary itself*, it's very hard to predict how changing source code will affect the size of that file.

> Does it also take too much time to resolve the shared_from_this() call?

You should expect the time that it takes to construct a `shared_ptr` from a `weak_ptr`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The correct question should be, how much size does it add. All clear, by the way. Thank you.

Comment: True. And it can't be *less* than two pointers with the current interface. In older Boost version the size was three times larger until I started to optimize it. I got it down to the mentioned two pointers. I also proposed to change the interface from `obj.shared_from_this()` into a free function `std::shared_from_this( obj )` which would have allowed to reduce the overhead to a *single* pointer, but that proposal on the Boost mailing list didn't get enough attention and therefore never made it to the standard :(

Answer (score 2):

You can look at boost source file. It's adds only `mutable weak_ptr<T> weak_this_;` to your class, which itself contains only pointer to instance and pointer to refcounter.